# Range Slider for text values

Tags: rangeslider

I need a range slider just like below site has the options  cut, Clarity and color has slider

http://www.lumeradiamonds.com/diamonds/search?shapes=B,PR,O,M,P,C,E,AS,R,H&

[image]

how to add range slider for color or text values like good better best
If anybody tell me how can i implement same slider in my site than its very helpful to me

Thanks

Comment: Questions to recommend products/projects are off topic for SO as they tend to generate a lot of differing opinions

Comment: i did not understand what u want to say

Comment: Hi, Deepak Goyal. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: did not find exact same but find different slider and add implement different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```js
function updateTextInput() {
    
    
    
 var value1 = Number(document.getElementById("range").value);
    var value2 = "";

    if ( value1 === 0 ) {
        value2 = "Blue Diamonds";
        // Insert more code here for what you intend to do
    }
    else if ( value1 === 1 ) {
        value2 = "Blue Diamonds";
        // Insert more code here for what you intend to do
    }
    else if ( value1 === 2 ) {
        value2 = "Red Diamonds";
        // Insert more code here for what you intend to do
    }
    else if ( value1 === 3 ) {
        value2 = "Black Diamonds";
        // Insert more code here for what you intend to do
    }
    else if ( value1 === 4 ) {
        value2 = "Green Diamonds";
        // Insert more code here for what you intend to do
    }

 document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = value2;
    
   
    
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="range" type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" step="1" max="4" value="2" class="white" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
  <input oninput="rangeInput.value=amount.value" id="box" type="text" value="0" name="amount" for="rangeInput" onkeyup="updateTextInput(this.value);" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" />
</form>

    <p id="value2">Red Diamonds</p>
```